# Random ORA-01403: no data found on same query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL package executing from java with a SELECT INTO statement which return no data found exception randomly. If i call the package again after an error it may run successfully.

Observations

1. with 2 active users error count was almost 0 (2 errors on 300 executions).
2. with more active application users almost every execution was failed (9 error per 10 execution).
3. table have a before insert trigger, which also fails but rarely.
4. Table is getting updated frequently but the row we query will not be updated during execution (package generates report);

Solutions Tried

1. Replaced SELECT INTO with CURSOR.
2. Executed same query 5 times in a loop with 5 second delay.

Error still occurring randomly.

```
BEGIN
  t_utility.init( p_log_level => '70', p_application => 'MFG', p_exe_reqst_id => p_cut_id);
  t_utility.info('Report Begins'||p_cut_id||'   '||p_report_size);
  FOR i IN 1..5
  LOOP
     BEGIN
        -- Fecthing the header details
        SELECT div.divisiont_code
        , fac.facility_code
        , cut_reg.cut_num
        , cut_reg.lay_date
        , cut_reg.revision_number
        , cut_reg.shrinkage
        , cut_reg.document_no
        , cut_reg.marker_name_method
        INTO l_division
        , l_facilty
        , l_doc_no
        , l_date
        , l_rev
        , l_shrinkage
        , l_cut_reg_num
        , l_marker_name
        FROM mfg.cut_regstr cut_reg
        , tnz.division div
        , tnz.facility fac
        WHERE cut_reg.op_code = 'C'
        AND div.id          = cut_reg.division
        AND fac.id(+)       = cut_reg.facility
        AND cut_reg.cut_regstr_id    = p_cut_id; --p_cut_id is an input parameter;
        l_exit_flag := 1;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
           t_utility.error('Header '||sqlerrm);
           --raise l_abort_package_exe;
           l_exit_flag := 0;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           t_utility.error('Header '||sqlerrm);
           l_exit_flag := 0;
           -- raise l_abort_package_exe;
     END;
     IF l_exit_flag = 1 THEN
        EXIT;
     END IF;
     sys.DBMS_LOCK.sleep (5);
  END LOOP;
  IF l_exit_flag = 0 THEN
     t_utility.error('Completed 5 iterations but result not found');
     raise l_abort_package_exe;
  END IF;
```

Comment: Provide the package body as well.

Comment: Show us what you have tried yet?

Comment: @JSapkota Sorry for the delayed response. Please find the beginning of package body in the edit.

Comment: @AvrajitRoyi tried following .Replaced SELECT INTO with CURSOR.
Executed same query 5 times in a loop with 5 second delay.

Comment: May i know why its down voted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with VPD (Virtual Private Database) Context. Everything worked fine when VPD is disabled.

I believe VPD context failed due to conflict in connection pool, as the issue only occurred when more than one user sessions were active.